# index.php not being loaded in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

It's to my understanding that by default the index.php page is loaded but on my wp site the homepage is blank yet if I go click on the sample page that comes default with wp my header etc is loaded. I have notice that nothing gets loaded on the default page including my CSS, JS etc. But this only happens with my theme> Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: URL of website OR screenshot?

Comment: check with The front page template file  front-page.php file also. it is used to index page